# Keycloak - how to allow linking accounts without registration

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am managing a Keycloak realm with only a single, fully-trusted external IdP added that is intended to be the default authentication mechanism for users.

I do **not** want to allow user to register, i.e. I want to manually create a local Keycloak user, and that user should then be allowed to link his external IdP account to the pre-existing Keycloak account, having the email address as common identifier. Users with access to the external IdP but without an existing Keycloak account should not be allowed to connect.

I tried the following *First Broker Login* settings, but whenever a user tries to login, he gets an error message (code: `invalid_user_credentials`).

[image]

Do you have any idea what my mistake might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like they integrated this feature in version 4.5.0.

See [automatic account link docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#automatically-link-existing-first-login-flow).

Basically you need to create a new flow and add 2 alternative executions:

1. Create User If Unique
2. Automatically Link Brokered Account

Comment: How do you do this prior to version 4.5, let's say in 3.4.3?

Comment: EDIT: Found the answer. If you want to do this prior to version 4.5.0 you can check it out here: https://github.com/ohioit/keycloak-link-idp-with-user

Comment: I am in a similar situation like in the original question, but unfortunately this creates the user if it does not exist, but the original post wanted that users without a pre-existing account were not able to authenticate.

Comment: Hello @Alvaro , did you find a solution please? I would like to log in the user by linking his idp account only if the account is already existing. If the account is not in my DB then he can't logs in

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got accepted. Like Alvaro and hakimovic said, a new user is created which was explicitly undesired. Any solution?

Comment: @hakimovic as I posted below, I found a solution by using a custom JavaScript authenticator.

Answer (score 11):

According to the doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#detect-existing-user-first-login-flow, you must create a new flow like this:
[image: screen of keycloak auth flow]

et voilà :)

Answer (score 2):

As per this discussion:

https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/link-idp-to-existing-user/1094/5

> It’s a bug in keycloak and they seem to be a reluctant to fix it for
> whatever reason. I have very few users so I solved it by manually
> querying the idp for the information keycloak uses and then copying it
> into the relevant fields in the UI. So there is no sign up process for
> my users I just make them myself. Obviously that’s a poor solution
> though, what we really need is someone to take over that PR and
> persuade the maintainers to merge it.

This is the PR: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6282

Answer (score 1):

As it is described in [this GitHub issue response](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6282#issuecomment-737728410) the solution is to use a [JavaScript authenticator](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers) that handles this.

In order to do so, you need to do the folowing:

1. Enable [custom authenticators using JavaScript in your server[(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#profiles) by https://stackoverflow.com/a/63274532/550222creating a file `profile.properties` in your configuration directory that contains the following:

   ```
    feature.scripts=enabled
   ```
2. Create the custom authenticator. You have to create a JAR file (essentially a ZIP file) with the following structure:

   ```
    META-INF/keycloak-scripts.json
    auth-user-must-exist.js
   ```

   The content of the files are in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/tulequ/f0d810d7bfcf6cb5db3bba5aad07b7cd), but I am including them here as well:

   - `META-INF/keycloak-scripts.json`:

     ```
     {
         "authenticators": [
             {
                 "name": "User must exists",
                 "fileName": "auth-user-must-exists.js",
                 "description": "User must exists"
             }
         ]
     }
     ```
   - `auth-user-must-exist.js`:

     ```
     AuthenticationFlowError = Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowError")
     ServicesLogger = Java.type("org.keycloak.services.ServicesLogger")       
     AbstractIdpAuthenticator = Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.broker.AbstractIdpAuthenticator")
     IdpCreateUserIfUniqueAuthenticator = Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.broker.IdpCreateUserIfUniqueAuthenticator")


     var IdpUserMustExists = Java.extend(IdpCreateUserIfUniqueAuthenticator)


     function authenticate(context) {                                         
         var auth = new IdpUserMustExists() {                                 
             authenticateImpl: function(context, serializedCtx, brokerContext) {
                 var parent = Java.super(auth)                                

                 var session = context.getSession()                           
                 var realm = context.getRealm()                               

                 var authSession = context.getAuthenticationSession()         

                 if (authSession.getAuthNote(AbstractIdpAuthenticator.EXISTING_USER_INFO) != null) {
                     context.attempted()                                      
                     return                                                   
                 }                                                            

                 var username = parent.getUsername(context, serializedCtx, brokerContext)
                 if (username == null) {                                      
                     ServicesLogger.LOGGER.resetFlow(realm.isRegistrationEmailAsUsername() ? "Email" : "Username")
                     authSession.setAuthNote(AbstractIdpAuthenticator.ENFORCE_UPDATE_PROFILE, "true")
                     context.resetFlow()                                      
                     return                                                   
                 }                                                            

                 var duplication = parent.checkExistingUser(context, username, serializedCtx, brokerContext)
                 if (duplication == null) {                                   
                     LOG.info("user not found " + username)                   
                     context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER) 
                     return                                                   
                 } else {                                                     
                     authSession.setAuthNote(AbstractIdpAuthenticator.EXISTING_USER_INFO, duplication.serialize())
                     context.attempted()                                      
                 }                                                            
             }                                                                
         }                                                                    

         auth.authenticate(context)                                           
     }
     ```
3. Then, you can define as follows:

   - User Must Exist -> ALTERNATIVE
   - Automatically Set Existing User -> ALTERNATIVE

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i am surprised by the keycloak auto creating behavior. I tried to add new Authentication flow as descibed here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#automatically-link-existing-first-login-flow

My flow :

1 - Create User If Unique [ALTERNATIVE]

2 - Automatically Link Brokered Account [ALTERNATIVE]

My use case : Authenticating users from Github ( Github as IDP )

Result :  when a github user logon with an existing "username" keycloak links the github account to my local user ( based on his username ). I expected using his email instead of username.